# flash cc vs. flash cc 2014

Tags: flash, trace, cc

I have the problem when I open my file in flash CC, I can't trace anything.
If I use this code in Flash CC, I only can see the trace when I close my file. When I click 100 times on the button, I don't see anything on runtime. But when I close my file, I will see all the 100 traces in the output.

When I open the same file in Flash CC 2014, there is no problem. Each click displays in my output on runtime.

Is there a bug in flash CC? Something I need to put on somewhere? Yesterday I've no problem with it, but it starts today....

`import flash.events.MouseEvent;

btnTest.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,addTrace);

function addTrace(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("hello world");
}`